# Tabs Within a VIM Split

Tags: vim, text-editors, javascript

I am writing a few different js files in my new favorite text editor, VIM.

Coming from ST2, I miss the feature of having splits with tabs. I.e: A split contains a collection of files which can be selected without affecting any others.

I ask this because I have a few separate plugins which I want to keep open (NERDTree being one) without having to re-run them in a new tab.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I understand exactly what you are asking for but vim splits are containers for files that can be selected without affecting other splits. Tabs are merely a higher level container on top of windows/splits.

Perhaps this (courtesy of the freenode #vim channels helpful vimgor bot) will be of some help?

```
23:13:19 <vimgor> For a quick intro to vim's windows, buffers, and tabs, see
                  http://oi56.tinypic.com/20gzol3.jpg and ':help tab-page-intro' and ':help
                  windows-intro'
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim has splits within tabs. Have a look at `:help :arglocal` though. There won't be GUI tabs as such, but it works in a similar way. Don't forget that vim has a dedicated mailing list/google group. You're more likely to get a quicker and more detailed set of responses there.